# Rails is not creating expected value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to setup a friendship feature in my Rails/Angular app, for that I'm following http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association tutorial.

On the Rails backend side I've created a friendship table,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

A friendship controller,

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
    redirect_to current_user
  end

  def index
    respond_with Friendship.all
  end

end
```

A friendship model,

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"

end
```

And added this to my user.rb model,

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
```

On the Angular side I have created a template that shows the current users and a link to add that user as a friend,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "user in users"}
  %li
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "addFriend(user)"} Add friend.
```

A user controller,

```
app.controller('usersCtrl', [

  '$scope', 'usersService', 'createFriend',
  function($scope, usersService, createFriend) {

    usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
      $scope.users = response.data;
      console.log ($scope.users)
    })

    $scope.addFriend = function (user) {
      console.log (user)

      createFriend.create({
        friend_id:   user.id
      })

      console.log ('friendrequest posted')
    }

  }
]);
```

And a user service,

```
app.factory('usersService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    loadUsers: function() {
      return $http.get('/users.json');
    }
  };
}])

app.factory('createFriend', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function() {
      return $http.post('/friendships.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

When I click the `add friend` link it triggers the `$scope.addFriend` function and in my Rails log I see this happening,

```
Started POST "/friendships.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-29 10:19:07 +0100
Processing by FriendshipsController#create as JSON
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "friendships" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-29 09:19:07.459234"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-29 09:19:07.459234"]]
   (12.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 14.7ms)
```

But nothing is actualy being posted. If I check `friendships.json` it's still empty. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Try using byebug to debug your `create` action in your rails controller. I suspect that your `params` variable is not populated as you expect it to be.

Comment: You should test your app step by step, it seems you have more than one mistake. At first write your restful APIs, test them by for example `postman`. Then test your angularjs codes, by browser debugger check all of your requests.

Comment: What means "I check `friendships.json`"? In your code there's created single `Friendship` model related with `User` with `id` 1 and his friend with `id` `nil`.

Comment: @Mareq If I check localhost:3000/friendships.json the output is empty. So nothing is being put in the database.

Comment: `GET friendships.json` is an output of `index` action of the `friendships` controller. Can you show this method? Of course if you didn't modified the routes and redirected it somewhere else.

Comment: @Mareq hm yea I didn't have a index definition on my friendships controller. I added `def index respond_with Friendship.all end` but it's still empty. I think the problem lies here `INSERT INTO "friendships" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)`. It seems like all the values are empty, and also the `friend_id` value is nowhere to find in the create function.

Comment: Apparently, you're not sending the friend_id in your params.

Comment: It seems so, but the tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true never mentions this.

Comment: I just checked in my Rails console `Friendship.all` and there are a lot of records in there. All of them are missing the `friend_id` paramater. But if there are records in the database, why are they not showing in the `friendships.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with the help of another user. The problem was that the `createfriend` service didn't pass the `user` data.

Changing it to this,

```
app.factory('createFriend', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function(user) {
      return $http.post('/friendships.json', user);
    }
  };
}])
```

(added user) fixed it.